# How to make a composite from two foreign keys? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table Atable ( 
a int, primary key(a)
);

create table Btable (
b int, primary key(b)
);

create table Ctable (
a int, b int,
foreign key(a) references Atable(a), 
foreign key(b) references Btable(b), //i dont want to these to be foreign keys, just two primary keys.. so a composite key.
primary key(a, b)
);
```

How to make a table C to have the primary key of the foreign key of Atable and Btable?

Sorry if I'm unclear. and sorry if this isn't even possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. (It can also have additional keys, but not primary keys...) What are you trying to achieve? School work?

Comment: This is possible. You can have a primary key that is composed by multiple columns. Also these columns can be foreign keys to other tables. It seems like you have a many-to-many relationship between A and B. So that makes C the middle table?

Comment: I dont get the question, I cant try it but your code seems to be fine and should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field can be a foreign key, a primary key, both or neither. CTable is an intersection between ATable and BTable, used to implement a many-to-many relationship between them. With intersection tables, it is common practice to make both of the foreign keys the composite primary key of the table.

This prevents duplicate relationships. A row from ATable can relate to many rows in BTable, but it cannot relate to the same row of BTable more than once (and vice versa).

```
Create table CTable(
    a   int not null,
    b   int not null,
    foreign key( a ) references ATable( a ),
    foreign key( b ) references BTable( b ),
    primary key( a, b )
);
```

So if you try to insert rows in CTable like this:

```
A1    B1
A1    B2
A2    B3
A3    B1
A3    B3
A3    B1  --> Not allowed
```

The last combination (A3, B1) would not be allowed because it has already been entered into the table. It doesn't make sense to define more than one relationship between the same two rows.